# python pandas calculate a mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
        pk_dcdata     threshold   last_ep  diff
window                                                            
1        11075761       0.00001         4     3
1        11075768       0.00001         7     6
2        11075769       0.00001         1    -1
2        11075770       0.00001         1    -1
3        11075771       0.00001         1     0
3        11075768       0.00001         7     6
```

I want to calculate the mean in the column 'diff' but compare with the index 'window', and save the mean into a new list. e.g. window = 1 and the mean is (3+6)/2, and the next is window = 2, so (-1-1)/2 and so on.

Expected outcome: `list = [4.5,-1,3]`

I tried to use 'rolling_mean' but don't know how to set the moving length. Because the dataset is big, hope can get a fast way to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `list` as variable because python reserved word.

Need aggregate by `mean` per index and last convert `Series` to `list`:

```
L = df.groupby(level=0)['diff'].mean().tolist()
#alternative
#L = df.groupby('window')['diff'].mean().tolist()
print (L)
[4.5, -1.0, 3.0]
```

Alternative working in `pandas 0.20.0+`, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-enhancements-groupby-access).

Comment: I would prefer `groupby('window')` as it is much more intuitive, but the answer looks correct.

Comment: @running.t - Yes, but it depends of version of pandas, answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby()`: let's say your dataframe is called `df`

```
avg_diff = df['diff'].groupby(level=0).mean()
```

This will provide you with a dataframe with the means based on the `window`.
If then you want to put it in a list you can do like this:

```
my_list = avg.tolist()
```

Comment: Sorry, what is difference with my solution?

Comment: When i started writing my solution there was none published yet this is why i went forth with it. The only difference in the two solutions would be a performance difference probably: selecting the column to groubpy before doing the mean (like in my solution) should provide faster computation as the computation is done on one column only.

Comment: OK, try test it by `np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcde') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'diff': np.random.randint(10000,size=N),
                   'window':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['window','diff']).set_index(['window'])`

Comment: I get `In [338]: %timeit df.groupby(level=0)['diff'].mean()
49 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [339]: %timeit df['diff'].groupby(level=0).mean()
1.11 s ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Ok this is interesting: doing `%timeit df['diff'].groupby(level=0).mean()` is indeed wierdly slow. doing `df[['diff']].groupby(level=0).mean()` is almost as fast as your solution though. Maybe it has to do with the way pandas `groupby()` worsk wit `Series` comapred to `DataFrame`. Thanks for the interesing comaprison.

Comment: Yes, I was surprise too, I think there should be less time difference. I learn in SO one thing - never say something is faster/slowier without some tests (but sometimes real data should be different, so it is only for fast sample comparison).